# GNAT Ada gprbuild execution data

Tags: compilation, statistics, ada, gnat

Capture and display GNAT Aada GPS compile date/time

Running GNAT Ada/GPS builds and I want to capture and display the date/time of the compile build to my user interface. Must I read the executable each time, or does the gpsbuild generate statistics I can capture.

Put("Build date/time are "); put(gpsbuild.datetime, Width =>10);
New_line;

Version Date Time ...
Main Menu My Program

Start Program  1
Run Set Up     2

Enter selection:

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, in GNAT GPS to display build number in "about" dialog they use placeholders in [config file](https://github.com/AdaCore/gps/blob/master/common/core/src/config.ads.in) and substitute them with real values in [configure file](https://github.com/AdaCore/gps/blob/f90d5fe866c129a2662acfe3da9e7d201579c2b0/configure.in#L5) with help of [AC_SUBST](https://github.com/AdaCore/gps/blob/f90d5fe866c129a2662acfe3da9e7d201579c2b0/configure.in#L187) routine. Not so easy way, but probably most optimal since AdaCore self do it.